# Do transactions in SQL Server lock all tables within the statement by default?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a T-SQL statement like so:

```
BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE dbo.TableA 
    ...
    ...
    ...

    DELETE FROM dbo.TableB

COMMIT TRAN
```

Suppose that the update on TableA is going to take some time.

By default, would SQL Server lock TableB until the transaction is completed? Would that mean you can't read or write to it while the update is ongoing?

Comment: T-SQL is a strictly sequential language. Nothing will even happen to `TableB` before the update to `TableA` is done. A transaction does not commit the server to a "point in time snapshot" or suchlike, that's always on a table by table basis.

Comment: Also, by default, SQL Server will always use **row-level locking** - it will not just lock entire tables - only those individual rows being affected by an operation.

Comment: A common misconception is that `BEGIN TRAN` / `COMMIT TRAN` form some sort of syntactic block, parsed and executed as a whole. They don't, they're separate statements. (If you never issue a `COMMIT TRAN`, the transaction will just hang around, until you close the connection and it's implicitly rolled back.) The server will take all the statements as they come. There's a separate `BEGIN ATOMIC` syntax that does treat a block as one integral part, but that's used only for in-memory operations.

Comment: @marc_s : I thought that row level locks could be automatically 'escalated' to page level and table level locks vy SQL as it sees fit - so an engineer might expect a certain class of records to be 'unlocked' by some other process, but this is not guaranteed, there could be an escalation to page or table locking

Comment: For all trying to answer this question, I find that it's hard to upvote these transaction-behavior related questions even when I see a potentially good answer because it's difficult to confirm.  If you all could give sources for your statements and inline relevant comments from such sources, then I'll be happy to upvote.

Comment: @Cato: yes, this is the case - **if** you have more than 5000 row-level locks in a single transaction, SQL Server will do lock escalation to the **table level** (not page level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **NO and NO**.

Long answer:
This is, in fact, a great question as it goes deep in transaction concepts and how the engine works but I guess a complete answer can occupy a good deal of a chapter on a good book and is out of the scope of this site.

**First**, keep in mind the engine can work in several isolation modes: snapshot, read committed, etc. I can recommend good research on this topic (this can take a few days).

**Second**, the engine has the granularity level and will try to use the "smallest" one but can escalate it on demand, depending on many factors, for example: "will this operation need a page split?"

**Third**, `BEGIN`, `COMMIT`, `ROLLBACK` work more in a "semaphore" way, flagging how changes are being phased from "memory" to "disk". It's a lot more complicated than it and that why I use quotes.

That said a "default transaction" will use a row granularity in a read committed isolation mode. Nothing says how locks will be issued one way or another.
It depends on stuff like foreign keys, triggers, how much of the table is being changed,  etc.

TLDR: It depends on a lot of minor details particular to your scenario. The best way to find out is by testing.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments of @Jeroen Mostert, @marc_s, and @Cato under the question, your locks on TableA and TableB here are likely to escalate to table exclusive locks as there is no "where" clause. If so, the other read and write operations from different connections may be affected based on their transaction isolation level until the end of this transaction.

Besides, locks are created on-demand; it means that the query first puts a lock on the tableA and after the execution of the update operation, it puts another lock on the tableB.

Comment: ***NO*** - SQL Server will **STILL** use row-level locks - just the absence of a `WHERE` clause does ***NOT*** change that ! SQL Server will escalate row-level locks to table-level locks if you have **more than 5000** rows affected by a single transaction

Comment: Thanks, @marc_s, for clarifying. I've updated my answer accordingly. It was my bad English, I think ;).